# Fetching data from laravel via axios in vue js

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3

I'm trying to fetch data from laravel but getting an error and I don't know< how to solve it

Here is my controller code:

```
class BookInventoryController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $data = Book::orderBy('title')->get();
        return response()->json(['books' => $data]);
    }
}
```

Here is a routes from api.php and web.php

```
Route::get('/api/books', [BookInventoryController::class, 'index'])->name('api/books');
Route::view('/', 'index');
```

Here is a code from my component where I'm trying to make a table and fill it with data from api

```
<template>
  <div class="m-8 w-7/12 mx-auto">
    <table class="min-w-full bg-white border border-gray-200">
            <tr class="bg-neutral-700 text-white">
                <td class="pl-8 py-3">Title</td>
                <td class="pl-8">Author</td>
                <td class="pl-8">Publication Year</td>
                <td class="pl-8">Publisher</td>
                <td class="pl-8">ISBN</td>
            </tr>
       
            <tr v-for="book in booksData" :key="book.id" class="border-b dark:border-neutral-300">
                <td class="p-5">{{book.title}}</td>
                <td class="p-5">{{book.author}}</td>
                <td class="p-5">{{book.publication_year}}</td>
                <td class="p-5">{{book.publisher}}</td>
                <td class="p-5">{{book.isbn}}</td>
            </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      booksData: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getBooks();
  },

  methods: {
    getBooks(){
        axios
            .get('/api/books')
            .then(response => {this.booksData = response.data.books})
            .catch(error => {
            console.log('Erroe:', error);
        });
    }
    
  },
};
</script>
```

The errors I'm getting
MainPage.vue:40     GET http://localhost/api/books 404 (Not Found)
Error: AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name...

Comment: are you sure that the backend and the frontend are listening on the same port?
you might need to set the frontend dev server to proxy to the backend one

Comment: Can you tell us, running URL of Vue and Laravel project. You aren't setting baseurl for axios, so it sends request from Vue project URL. If you aren't proxying it, you aren't sending request to your backend

Answer (score 0):

This error happens because the frontend (axios) is not finding the laravel service on localhost, as it is probably running on another port.

Try the following:

1. Ensure Laravel is running on port 8080 - note: the port can be whatever you define:

   `php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8080`
2. In the axios GET call, instead of calling the route directly, add this URL:

   `axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/books')`

Comment: Sorry, but it's not works. I'm using xampp so my localhost server is running on 80's port. I tried to use this code: `axios.get('http://localhost:80/api/books')` with 80's port, but it does't works. I also tried to set proxy in vite.config.js like this ` server: {
      proxy: {
        '/api': 'http://localhost/Book_inventory/public',
      },
    },`. It also doesn't works. Maybe I'm doing something wrong but I'm new at vue js so I don't know how to make it work

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you run the vue project by npm run serve and laravel project by php artisan serve. That means your vue project will run on port 8080 by default and laravel project on 8000 by default.

Since the vue and laravel are running on different port, maybe on different host on future. You need to specify the base path while fetching the axios request.

Your code:

```
axios
    .get('/api/books')
    .then(response => {this.booksData = response.data.books})
    .catch(error => {
     .console.log('Erroe:', error);
});
```

Fixed one:

```
const base_url = "http://localhost:8000"; 
axios
    .get(`${base_url}/api/books`)
    .then(response => {this.booksData = response.data.books})
    .catch(error => {
     .console.log('Erroe:', error);
});
```

here, i am using the laravel is running on localhost and port 8000,
since you stated that it is running on port 80,
you can try writing 80 instead of 8000

try writing the whole path. instead of just route "/api/books/"
when writing on "/api/books/"
axios will request on the same base path, if your vue is running on `localhost:8080` then axios will request like `localhost:8080/api/books/`